# Flask - Passing only selected fields

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a flask webpage that asks for the user to select few fields and returns back output based on the fields selected.

The below code works just fine with 3 fields. If the user selects all the 3 fields there are no issues. However if any of the fields are not selected, it returns an error saying column "none" does not exist.

```
def template():
    form = TestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        student_id = form.student_id.data
        class_id = form.class_id.data
        roll_id = form.roll_id.data
        print(student_id)
        print(class_id)
        print(roll_id)
```

Could anyone assist on how I could modify this such that only fields selected are passed and the unselected fields are ignored. Thanks

Edit (HTML code):

```
<form action=""
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          method="POST">
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
        <table>

            <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="student_id" value="student_id"> student_id
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="class_id" value="class_id"> class_id
            </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="roll_id" value="roll_id"> roll_id
            </label>
            </div>
            <tr class="submit">
                <td></td>
                <td><button type="submit">Get the Report!</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Query that runs after getting user input:

```
def function(*field_names):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select {} from enrolments'.format(', '.join(str(field) for field in field_names)))
    print(field_names)
    output_file = dwh_cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Show your HTML and your validation code. It sounds like you have your select field value defaulting to "none". You probably want to default it to an empty string or change your validation

Comment: @Cfreak have included the HTML code in my initial post.

Comment: Show us how you call `function`, also consider renaming it.  Secondly, if `field_names` are coming directly from the value of your HTML, then this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You want to specify the columns to select. Generally for checkboxes the value attribute should be a true or false value to decide if it's selected or not.  The columns you select should be static and, you would use a `WHERE` statement in your SQL to control which rows you get back.

Comment: @Cfreak, this function hits a temp table that would have maximum of 10 records and this will only fetch 3 samples from that list. Sure would rename the function appropriately. However I am stuck on how to get past these non selected fields that return 'None'